# How Can I convert this ScratchPad Request Detail To PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl

```
POST /Orders/2011-01-01?AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey
&Action=ListOrders
&SellerId=SellerId
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2012-12-12T08%3A31%3A19Z
&Version=2011-01-01
&Signature=MySignature
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&CreatedAfter=2012-12-06T19%3A00%3A00Z
&MarketplaceId.Id.1=MyMarketID HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.co.uk
x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)
Content-Type: text/xml
```

I have tried to convert these request detail of amazon scratch pad to php curl but all in vain. any one know how to convert these.

Below is code snipped not all but a part of code.
Nothing is displaying

```
 $params = array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        'Action' => "ListOrders",
               'SellerId' => MERCHANT_ID,
       'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
       'SignatureVersion' => "2",
   'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
     'Version'=> "2011-10-01",
   'MarketplaceId' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
   );



 // Sort the URL parameters
 $url_parts = array();
  foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
  $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
 sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
 $url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);

$string_to_sign = "POST\nmws.amazonservices.co.uk\n/Orders/2011-10-01\n" . $url_string;

 // Sign the request
 $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

 //Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
  $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Curl GetInfo

```
[content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [redirect_url] => )
```

URL

```
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Orders/2011-01-01?AWSAccessKeyId=myaccesskey&Action=ListOrders&CreatedAfter=2012-12-06T19%253A00%253A00Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=marketplaceiddumy&SellerId=selleriddummy&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-12-12T13%3A16%3A56.000Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=lXaoVq1n4b0gAmoMg69jnSCqHWC6C6hlbEfTtrHX2i0%3D
```

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? Show us your implementation code.

Comment: What's the print of `curl_getinfo($ch);`? Set `CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE` and show the response header.

Comment: @Ranty curl_getinfo updated.

Comment: now the error is Sender InvalidAddress Invalid Section name or version provided - Orders/2011-10-01 0596dd32-4206-49be-815b-0da584c54fb6

Comment: @abdulwakeel You need to call `curl_getinfo` before `curl_close`, but after `curl_exec`. As for the response, it gives you the errors. See their API for clues, the fields you supplied wrong are there in the response.

Comment: [content_type] => text/xml [http_code] => 404 [header_size] => 384 [request_size] => 525 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 20 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 2.964 [namelookup_time] => 1.591 [connect_time] => 1.857 [pretransfer_time] => 2.434 [size_upload] => 299 [size_download] => 318 [speed_download] => 107 [speed_upload] => 100 [download_content_length] => 318 [upload_content_length] => 299 [starttransfer_time] => 2.699 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 178.236.5.114 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 110.39.161.36 [local_port] => 11621

Comment: @Ranty thanks, above is the curl-getinfo response.

Comment: Something is wrong with your request. I get return code of `400` with my browser request on the URL you provided, while you get `404` with curl. See their API for clues, I can only speculate on which headers and settings are required.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 13:49:48 GMT Server: Server x-mws-request-id: 83fb3f52-a3e9-4521-9ec7-8db330491f5b x-mws-timestamp: 2012-12-12T13:49:48.788Z x-mws-response-context: F1bffg4j5B7CSFwbBmD6R4k8fj3kxSGamCxb5BUdXghb27bg4XPqMcB7S10i2+X+pS8wUzzYTUI= Content-Type: text/xml Content-Length: 318 Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Sender InvalidAddress Invalid Section name or version provided - Orders/2011-10-01

Comment: can you suggest what thing may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change TimeStamp and some other vars, and its works.

```
 $params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'Action' => 'ListOrders',
    'SellerId' => MERCHANT_ID,
    'SignatureVersion' => '2',
    'Version'=> '2011-01-01',
    'OrderStatus.Status.1'=> 'Unshipped',
    'OrderStatus.Status.2'=> 'PartiallyShipped',
    'SignatureMethod' => 'HmacSHA256',
    'CreatedAfter'=>'2012-12-06T19:00:00Z',
    'MarketplaceId.Id.1' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
   );
$params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$url_string = trim($url_string, '&');
$string_to_sign = "POST" . "\n" ."mws.amazonservices.co.uk"."\n"."/Orders/2011-01-01"."\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
////echo AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, True));
        $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

$url = 'https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Orders/2011-01-01?' . $url_string . '&Signature=' . $signature;

$headers   = array("Content-Type: text/xml");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);


//echo $url_string;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $headers);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
//$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
//return ($parsed_xml);
return $response;
```